# What predefined macro can be used to detect debug build with clang?

Tags: c++, debugging, clang

MSVC defines `_DEBUG` in debug mode, gcc defines `NDEBUG` in release mode. What macro can I use in clang to detect whether the code is being compiled for release or debug?

Comment: Take a look to this: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros

Comment: Visual Studio also defines `NDEBUG` for Release builds using the default project settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the project settings of your IDE, you will see that those macros are actually manually defined there, they are not automatically defined by the compiler. In fact, there is no way for the compiler to actually know if it's building a "debug" or "release", it just builds depending on the flags provided to it by the user (or IDE).

You have to make your own macros and define them manually, just like the IDE does for you when creating the projects.

Comment: There is a way for compiler to know whether it's debug or release build - flags that are specific for one or the other mode. Like `-g` for gcc / clang. But it seems that you're right, clang doesn't define any additional macros when invoked with `-g`. Too bad!

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Not really, you can make a "release build" with debug information, or a "debug" build with optimizations. The first case (add debug information to a "release" build) can be quite useful sometimes.

Comment: Either way a macro that is automatically defined when the compiler is called with `-g` would do the trick.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The `-g` compiler option merely says to generate debugging information. Unfortunately, gcc compiles this information **into** the binary, making it look like it's part of the compilation process. MSC does the right thing and simply produces a symbol database (pdb) file, making the distinction easier to see. This has nothing to do with a Debug build - it simply allows to get human-readable information out of a crash dump. I would assume that everyone generates debugging information for released software.

Answer (score 7):

Compilers don't define those macros. Your IDE/Makefile/`<insert build system here>` does. This doesn't depend on the compiler, but on the environment/build helper program you use.

The **convention** is to define the `DEBUG` macro in debug mode and the `NDEBUG` macro in release mode.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `__OPTIMIZE__` flag to determine if optimization is taking place. That generally means it is not a debug build since optimizations often rearrange the code sequence. Trying to step through optimized code can be confusing.

This probably is what those most interested in this question really are attempting to figure out.

Comment: That will do! It's not about optimization itself; the `DEBUG`, `NDEBUG` and similar macros are usually used to insert code into debug build that should not be present in a final production build. Like additional error checking. But since production build is pretty much always optimized, this is indeed a good way to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a *debug mode* in a command line compiler. That is a IDE thing: it just sets up some options to be sent to the compiler.

If you use `clang` from the command line, you can use whatever you want. The same is true for `gcc`, so if with `gcc` you use `NDEBUG` you can use just the same.