# CMake: Set different name for #cmakedefine variable

Tags: c++, cmake, preprocessor-directive

I know you can use CMake's `configure_file` to make CMake variables available to your program. For example, I can use

```
#define ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
```

resulting in

```
#define Release
```

However, to keep my code more readible, I would prefer to define

```
#define BUILD_TYPE_RELEASE
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly simple way to solve it:

In `CMakesLists.txt`:

```
if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

string (TOUPPER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} BUILD_TYPE_NAME)

configure_file (config.h.in config.h)
```

And in `config.h.in`:

```
#define BUILD_TYPE_${BUILD_TYPE_NAME}
```

I am, however, still curious if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: How is this more readable? Just get used to the `${}` syntax or use a different language!

Comment: @usr1234567: `How is this more readable` - More readable than **what**? Asker doesn't provide any way for achive that (transforming value of variable into uppercase). His "more readable" relates to C (or C++) code which uses configured header, not to the *CMakeLists.txt* script.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question of your preferred programming style (configuration files vs. compiler definitions).

In your case I would use [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) or directly modify/append [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) directory property (using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) also supports multi-configuration environments):

```
set_property(
    DIRECTORY 
    APPEND 
    PROPERTY 
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BUILD_TYPE_$<UPPER_CASE:$<CONFIG>>"
)
```

**Most simplified Debug/Release Check**

You can also check what compiler definitions CMake does pre-define. Without having to modify/add something to your `CMakeLists.txt` files you could simply check for `NDEBUG` definition (set for Release builds across platforms) in you C/C++ code:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
... 
#endif
```

**References**

- [CMake: How to pass preprocessor macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639449/cmake-how-to-pass-preprocessor-macros)
- [How to check if a CMake build directory build type is Debug or Release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164166/how-to-check-if-a-cmake-build-directory-build-type-is-debug-or-release)
- [What predefined macro can be used to detect debug build with clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635630/what-predefined-macro-can-be-used-to-detect-debug-build-with-clang)